# Problem with Matlab multivariate normal distribution (mvncdf)

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix

I want to create a normal distribution with a MU = 0 and SIGMA = cov(A); A is a 4000*5460 matrix.
I get this error: SIGMA must be a square, symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Since the error is related to the Cholesky transformation and negative eignvalues, I used SVD and retained first positive 745 eigenvalues which describe 95% of variance.
Using this new SIGMA, I get the same error.

Comment: why is it that with A=randi([-10 10],4000,5460);B=cov(A); I don't get any error? what do you have in A? complex values?